# How to Rspec test a method that only requires a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In my rails engine's config.rb I have a public method like this

```
def require_this_file
  require 'this_file'
end
```

The file that is being required is adding a filter to ApplicationController

```
module ActionController
  class Base
    before_filter :do_something

    def do_something
    end
  end
end
```

What is the conventional way to test this in rspec?

Comment: This seems like an unnecessary test.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good method to require modules in a method. But you can simply test if a method specific to this module is present, like this : `controller.should respond_to?(:a_method)`.

Comment: mcfinnigan- I thought so too because it is like I am testing Ruby, but I would like to keep loc coverage at a 100%.

Comment: Why are you dynamically including a file? Just require it from an initializer and be done with it. You can't un-require a file once it's required; you can't add that functionality per-request with a require.

Comment: This is dynamic because it is in an engine that is being consumed by many apps. The consuming app can add the functionality in an initializer. Not all apps have the dependencies for this functionality therefore it cannot be required for all applications

Answer (score 0):

Trying to move away from the should syntax. This is what a colleague of mine came up with and LOC is at a %100. Thanks!

```
let(:some_file) { 'file' } 

it 'adds_file' do
  expect(@configuration).to receive(:require).with(some_file)
  @configuration.require_this_file
end
```